# how to replace the special characters from file using shell script

Tags: shell, sed, cut

i have fixed length file like

```
1234INen %^&           198787655
1234dnen %^& ($#       1987989809
```

i want just want to replace this special characters with *

I used cut command, but it is trimming the spaces between the fields.

```
cut -c 5-10
```

how to replace that special character without changing the input format and length.

some one please suggest sed command for repalce

Comment: So you want to replace even non-alphanumeric and non-space by `*`?

Comment: i just want to replace the fixed length from 9-16 with  * like 1234INen %^&           198787655 this should be 1234INen *             198787655

Comment: ok check updated answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed command:

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/*/g' file
1234INen ***           198787655
1234dnen *** ***       1987989809
```

**UPDATE:** As per op's comments: `from length 9-16 i just want to replace with *`

Use this sed:

```
sed -r 's/^(.{9}).{8}/\1********/g' file
1234INen ********      198787655
1234dnen ********      1987989809
```

Comment: Hi thanks lot.. its working  and i want to replace * and other fixed length with sapce like the following 1234INen *               198787655

Answer (score 0):

Just cut out everything you want to include your output, thus leaving out what you don't want there. For example to leave out characters from "columns" 5-10, use `cut -c1-4,11-` and then format the output to your liking with awk, e.g. `cut -c1-4,11- < your_file.txt | awk '{ f=$1 ; $1="" ; printf "%s    %s\n", f, $0 }'` (this will print out the first "column" and then a few spaces followed by the rest of "columns).

Answer (score 0):

To remove non-printable characters you can try this, provided you have a sed that supports POSIX character classes (e.g. modern Linux):

```
sed -r 's/[^[:print:]]//' input.file > final.file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed "s/[[:punct:]]/*/g"
```

Use `--posix` for GNU sed

Answer (score 0):

If the input is in predictable columns, `awk` with FIELDWIDTHS might be the way to go. You can easily get what you describe with something like this:

```
awk '{$2="*"}1' FIELDWIDTHS='8 8 16' infile
```

Output:

```
1234INen *        198787655
1234dnen *        198798980
```

But there is a lot of extra white-space. Perhaps is is enough to print the first and last fields?

```
awk '{print $1, "*", $NF}' infile
```

Output:

```
1234INen * 198787655
1234dnen * 1987989809
```